# howto write email pattern in mysql?

Tags: mysql

What I've tried is as below:

```
mysql> select 'abc@b.c' REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:[\-\+\.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:[\-\.\+][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:[\-\.\+][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*';
```

ERROR 1139 (42000): Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

And I've no idea what's wrong with it.

Can anyone here give me the right one that can work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Trying to match email addresses with regexes will lead you down a long path of pain. For the love of all that's sane, don't do it.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young : matching is fine, as long as you're OK with some false positives.  The pain comes in when trying to do any rigorous validation.

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex that should match most email addresses:

```
[A-z0-9_.%+-]+@[A-z0-9_.%+-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) to learn about checking email with regexps. It appears it's a quite complex problem :-)